# Redirecting to page after using PHPExcel to create spreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
// I have excluded lines here that successfully create a spreadsheet using PHPExcel
// ...
// ...
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=spreadsheet.xlsx");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($filename);
readfile($filename);
// Now create a webpage for display
include 'import.php';
exit();
```

The import.php file should then create a web page.
However doing this does not work - instead the contents of that webpage are added to the spreadsheet.

If I replace `include 'import.php';` with `header('Location: login.php?import');` and then try to check if `$_GET['import']` has been set, this also fails.

How can I go to a page created by import.php immediately after downloading the spreadsheet to the browser?

Comment: Are you Solved your problem?

Comment: I guess, a good start would be to close/unset all the objects, which are still open and not needed anymore. For example `unset($objPHPExcel);`

Comment: I have tried to unset objPHPExcel, but the problem still persists.  Is there some way I can close the header statements to indicate that spreadsheet is complete?